# Does Calabash-iOS support deep linking?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, calabash, calabash-ios

I would like to know if calabash supports deep linking, I need to access a section of my native app through a link.
If it does support it, could you refer some example?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you want to trigger it? Because with calabash-ios you can only test inside your app. You can not interact with the OS as such.

Comment: I was wondering if there is some functionality on calabash to send as a parameter the URI and handle it to open such part of the native app. Since as you said, I can't interact with the OS as such.

Answer (score 1):

Calabash does not support that type of operation directly.

What you can do, however, is create a backdoor method which triggers the same functionality.

E.g., suppose when your app is opened via URL `myapp://?key=value`, you are handling the necessary logic in `AppDelegate.m` with a function called

```
- (void)handleOpeningAppWithURL:(NSURL *)url { 
    /* parse url, etc...*/
}
```

Then you could have a backdoor method in your app delegate, say:

```
- (NSString *)backdoorOpenWithURLString:(NSString *)urlString {
    [self handleOpeningAppWithURL:[NSURL urlFromString:urlString]];
    return nil;
}
```

And invoke it from calabash via:

```
backdoor "backdoorOpenWithURLString:", "myapp://?key=value"
```